# Word for "english-like syntax"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to write a sentence like do:

> The syntax of high-level programming languages are more english-like than lower-level programming languages like Assembly.

I'm looking for a word that represents "english-like" - something that comes to mind would be "anglic", but that's not a word.

Comment: It should be *is* more English-like because you have a singular subject (*syntax*). That aside, why can't you just say *more like English*?

Comment: I would say "chaotic syntax".

Answer (score 2):

"The syntax of [many] high-level programming languages uses Subject-Verb-Object, an english-like ordering. Pascal, C, C++, Java, and many other programming languages are SVO."

Subject-Verb-Object (SVO) ordering looks like, "X += Y". This is English's predominant form.

Conversely, many assembler variants use Verb-Subject-Object (VSO) as in, "ADD R1, R3". (One reason that C is an "efficient" language is that the SVO example can directly compile to the VSO.)

Note that high-level stack languages like Postscript and Forth use SOV: "X, Y, ADD".

More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_typology#Subject–verb–object_positioning